# GridBag Panel not Taking up All the Space

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a list of rows with labels in columns. I'm trying to use a gridbaglayout, but I'm running into  a problem. When I expand the window, it doesn't expand. This is what happens:
[image]

What I really want is for it cell in the layout to take up a 1/5 of the space, with the labels shifted to the left most part of the cell.

```
   public static JPanel createLayout(int rows) {
    JPanel product = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    String[] lables = {"School", "Advanced #", "Novice #"};
    double weight = 1/(lables.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.gridx = i;
        c.weightx = weight;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        for (int j = 0; j < lables.length; j++) {

            JLabel l = new JLabel(lables[j]);
            product.add(l, c);
        }
    }
    return product;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Debate Calculator");
    JPanel debates = new JPanel();
    frame.add(createLayout(5), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your weight calculation...

```
double weight = 1/(lables.length);
```

Because `1` and `lables.length` are both int values, Java is automatically converting the result to a `int` (which is `0`).

Instead, try something like...

```
double weight = 1d/(double)lables.length;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a side question: when I set the ancor equal to GridBagConstraints.CENTER and apply it to a label, it doesn't work. How else can i center the label in a cell?

Comment: This will depend on the `fill` property of the `GridBagConstraint`, if it is `HORIZONTAL` or `BOTH`, then the label it self will need it's horizontal position to be set using `JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER)`, you also look at ``JLabel#setVerticalAlignment` as well